# Register multiple application in Azure

Tags: c#, ios, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We have multiple iOS mobile application. We are planning to use Azure Active Directory for authentication to take advantage of the SSO using MSAL.

For app registration, if we have multiple iOS application, do we need to create an app registration for each application or can we just use 1 app registration for all the mobile application that we have?

Comment: Are they internal apps or customer-facing apps? Do you need to separate your users? if yes, you may need to create multiple app registrations.

Comment: Yes, they are internal apps.

Comment: I have multiple iOS app but it will be accessible for single organization. Can we use 1 app registration in all the apps? Bundle ID in App registration is not accepting wild card(*)

Comment: if you don't need to separate users, i think you can just use 1 app registration.

Comment: AlexJiang, ok, but in the app registration it is not allowing to add a wildcard bundle ID.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Alex Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3973524/alex-jiang),

If you have multiple iOS mobile applications, ***you have to create multiple app registrations in Azure AD.***

If you want your application to be accessible for multiple organizations, while registering select supported account type as ***multi-tenant***.

To know how to register IOS mobile application with Azure AD, please refer the below link,

[Add Authentication on iOS - Azure Mobile Apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-users#register).

Comment: I have multiple iOS app but it will be accessible for single organization. Can we use 1 app registration in all the apps? Bundle ID in App registration is not accepting wild card(*)